# Is it correct to use "neither", "nor" and "but" together?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically and stylistically correct?

> They mightn't experience neither obsession nor attraction but real
>   love.

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't use 'might not' with 'neither ... nor' because that's a double negative. "They _might_ experience neither obsession nor attraction but real love' would be correct.

Comment: @BoldBen Sadly, perhaps they didn't experience real love, and the tortured sentence expresses their feeling.

Comment: And adding to the first comment, drop the article—it's just *real love*, not *the real love*.

Comment: What's the context? Based on just what you wrote here it could perhaps be re-written to: "They might not experience obsession, nor attraction -- but real love".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the sentence to be rewritten without the double negative:

> They might experience neither obsession nor attraction but real love.

You could even split it into two sentences, especially for spoken conversation:

> What they might experience is neither obsession nor attraction. It is real love.